# Error while loading an image directory using glob() into a label detection tool

Tags: python, pandas, opencv, image-processing, python-tesseract

A label detection tool that automatically identifies and outputs the image labels based on equipment numbers into an excel spreadsheet. I have been trying to detect the labels of an entire folder of images which is being loaded using the glob(). Unfortunately, there seems to be an attribute error (image attached) that doesn't load all the images that need to be processed. It's my first time using the glob() function and am pretty new to coding. Any help on easier methods to recursively find and load images in an input directory would be greatly appreciated!

Sample Input Image]:

[image: Sample Input Image]

Attribute Error:

[image: Attribute Error]

```
import re
import cv2
import glob
import imutils  # resizeimage
import pytesseract
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import pandas as pd

#Load input image directory
image = [cv2.imread(file) for file in glob.glob('Image Samples/CE Test Pics/*.JPG')]
for im in image: plt.figure()
plt.imshow(im)
plt.show()

# Resize the image - change width to 500
image = imutils.resize(image, width=500)

# Display the original image
cv2.imshow("Original Image", image)
cv2.waitKey(0)

# Convert image to string using PyTesseract
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(image, lang='eng', config='--psm 11')

# Recognizes contract number (modify according to business needs)
for line in text.split('\n'):
    #  Detects two digits, a hyphen, five digits or characters, a space, and then two digits or characters
    if re.match(r'^\d{2}-\w{5} \w{2}$', line):
        print(line)
    elif re.match(r'^\d{2}-\w{4}', line):
        print(line)
    elif re.match(r'^\d{2}-\w{5}', line):
        print(line)
    elif re.match(r'^\d{2}-\w{6}', line):
        print(line)
    elif re.match(r'^\d{2}-\d{4}\w{1}$', line):
        print(line)
    elif re.match(r'^\w{2}-\d{4}\w{2}$', line):
        print(line)

df = pd.DataFrame({'Original Image': image,
    'Contract Number': line})

df = pd.DataFrame({'Original Image': image,
    'Contract Number': line})
# print(text)


df.to_excel('./ContractNumberTest.xlsx',  sheet_name= 'Air Testing', index = False)
```

Comment: you are trying to resize a list of images, but you want to resize the image itself

Comment: hey luigigi - appreciate the help! What would be the best way to recursively resize all the images in order to make it easier to pre-process the images for the OCR tool (pytesseract)?